# Cannot use write() or read() calls on I2C device, but echo and i2c-tools work

Tags: linux, timeout, driver, embedded-linux, i2c

I am trying to read and write from I2C devices on embedded linux (4.6). I can use `i2cset`, `i2cget`, and `i2cdetect` to interact with my devices fine. I can also use `echo` and `ca`t to read/write from the device driver (`i2c-ocores`).

However, any code I build that tries to do this with calls to `write()` and `read()` always fail with a "Connection timed out". Opening the device file works:

```
fd = open("/dev/i2c-10", O_RDWR);
```

Setting the slave address works:

```
ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, addr);
```

But writing or reading returns `-1` and sets errno to "Connection timed out"

```
write(fd, buffer, len);
```

Also, once I try to write or read this way, it breaks the I2C bus and I have to reload the module to get it working again with `i2c-tools`. I have also tried using the various other ways to write to the i2c drivers (`ioctl` calls with `i2c_rdwr_ioctl_data` messages, `i2c_smbus_ioctl_data` messages) to no avail, they return the same error messages.

I can't for the life of me think of any reason that `write()` and `read()` calls would work any differently in my code than in `i2c-tools` and `echo`. In fact, I've even compiled my program with the `i2c-tools` source code (busybox 1.26.2) and directly used the same functions that `i2cset` and `i2cget` use... and it *still* doesn't work.

Any help or suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I've got exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use strace with your echo or i2cset call. Use strace with your code. Compare the systemcalls.